# Getting past syntax error when executing two selects at once

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I do this sql query correctly so It wont throw the error

> SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near ') d on d.userId = us.userId set us.published =
>   d.published, us.inactive = d.in' at line 1

The error is thrown when I add the second select in the statement.

```
update userStats us
join (select
  userId,
  sum(postStatus = 0) published,
  sum(postStatus = 1) inactive,
  sum(postStatus = 5) recalled,
  sum(postStatus = 6) deleted
from userData where userId = 1;

select 
    sum(postStatus = 10) unChecked
from userDataMod where userId = 1;// This causes the error.

) d on d.userId = us.userId set
us.published = d.published,
us.inactive = d.inactive,
us.recalled = d.recalled,
us.deleted = d.deleted
us.unChekced = d.unChecked
;
```

I've seen a few examples that run queries like this, but this one throws an error. I cannot use union or anything else in there. How do I get this right?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this? You have one SQL statement, but you want to split it somehow?

Comment: I'm pretty sure its indicating that the error is on the closing ) beside 'd on d.userId', not on the statement preceeding that.

Comment: Why is there a ' ; ' in the middle of your query ?!

Comment: Ok. I updated the sql and question.

Comment: First: Double slashes are not valid to begin sql comments. Second: Do you think the statement following your comment is a valid sql statement?

Comment: Still your desired behavior is unclear.

Comment: @VMai That's only for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
   UPDATE userStats us
LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT userId,
              SUM(postStatus = 0) published,
              SUM(postStatus = 1) inactive,
              SUM(postStatus = 5) recalled,
              SUM(postStatus = 6) deleted
         FROM userData
     GROUP BY userId
          ) ud
       ON us.userId = ud.userId 
LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT userId,
              SUM(postStatus = 10) unchecked
         FROM userDataMod 
     GROUP BY userId
          ) udm
       ON us.userId = udm.userId
      SET us.published = COALESCE(ud.published,0),
          us.inactive = COALESCE(ud.inactive,0),
          us.recalled = COALESCE(ud.recalled,0),
          us.deleted = COALESCE(ud.deleted,0),
          us.unchecked = COALESCE(udm.unchecked,0)
    WHERE us.userID = 1
```

Comment: Your previous answer works very well. There wont always be rows in both the tables for that particular user, so it need to works even when there are rows in one table. I think your previous answer does that.

Comment: @Norman, this one is the same, but only has the `WHERE userID = 1` in one place so it is easier to maintain. This one works for cases where one table has more than one row, or either have no rows.

Comment: @Norman You can also drop the `WHERE` now and it'll do the whole table correctly.

Comment: I think the `where` will be a good idea. Your answer (if I'm not mistaken), will select the entire table instead of just userId 1 and then group it. Am I right?

Comment: @Norman Without the `WHERE` the whole table will be updated, but the counts for each row will be correct for each row's particular `userId` and each column's conditions. That's the joy of `UPDATE ... JOIN`!

Comment: I meant the `where` inside the selects.

Comment: @Norman Ah yes, conceptually you are correct, but the optimiser should handle it so it should be roughly the same speed. You can benchmark it if you like. It is more powerful without, because you can update as many rows of `userStats` as you want and only have to filter them in one place.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the query that you want:

```
update userStats us join
       (select userId, sum(postStatus = 0) as published,
               sum(postStatus = 1) as inactive,
               sum(postStatus = 5) as recalled,
               sum(postStatus = 6) as deleted,
               (select sum(postStatus = 10) from userDataMod where userId = 1) as Unchecked
        from userData
        where userId = 1
       ) d
       on us.userid = d.userid
    set us.published = d.published,
        us.inactive = d.inactive,
        us.recalled = d.recalled,
        us.deleted = d.deleted
        us.unChekced = d.unChecked;
```

The major problem is that you cannot have semicolons in the middle of the query.  I think your placement of the subqueries was also off.

Comment: Is it possible to something like the way I've done in my question, because there are more rows I wish to select from the second table, and not just one as you've done. When I do `sum(postStatus = 6) as deleted,
               (select sum(postStatus = 10) as unChecked from userDataMod where userId = 1)
        from userData
        where userId = 1
       ) d` I get an error.